# Export to CSV after doing left join query in tables

Tags: mysql

Is there a way we can export to CSV of the result set of sql output of tables joint with left joins?

I want to be able to get tree based data output in CSV if possible in MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select-into.html)

```
SELECT ...
INTO OUTFILE 'export.csv'
FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES
        TERMINATED BY '\n'

FROM ...;
```

Note: Here `export.csv` will be saved in the database folder in home path of `mysql` user. **Any path in `select ... into outfile` it may not work if `mysql` user has no access there**. In linux mysql home path can be found by  grepping `/etc/password`

```
grep -i mysql /etc/passwd
mysql:x:111:117:MySQL Server,,,:/var/lib/mysql:/bin/false
#                                  ^        
#                                  |
#  Home path of mysql -------------+
```

If the database name is `db1` them export.csv can be found in `/var/lib/mysql/db1/export.csv`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ...
INTO OUTFILE '/home/www/servers/www.servername.de/tmp/export.csv'
FIELDS
        TERMINATED BY ';'
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
FROM ...;
```